# Remove RSS feed default image and assign another image in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

How to do, if i want to remove the default image from rss feed and assign another image

Answer (score 0):

you will have to replace the image on your server. The easiest way to do this is to (while using Firefox) right click on the image and click "Copy Image Location" then past it in a new web browser and it will give you the path to your email. You can also try it in IE by Right Click and then properties. Another way of doing this is to use a Joomla! extension which will allow you to modify it.

Hope it helps!